# VTS suite doesn't run because of exception

Tags: android, android-vts

I tried to run the vts suite with:

```
run vts
```

But it doesn't run any module and gives this exception:

```
 I/ResultReporter: Invocation finished in 4s. PASSED: 0, FAILED: 0, MODULES: 0 of 150
```

and gives the following exception

```
E/CommandScheduler: com.android.tradefed.targetprep.TargetSetupError: Failed to create virtualenv
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tradefed.targetprep.TargetSetupError: Failed to create virtualenv
```

Comment: did you resolve this problem? I encountered this one too. virtualenv has been installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed virtualenv and still you are facing this issue, you have to check your proxy settings.

Set http_proxy and https_proxy variables and then you re-run the vts again.

Note :
1) http_proxy & https_proxy can be set in Start -> Edit the environment variables in Windows.
2) In Linux you can set it by changing /etc/environment file.
3) Proxy differs from system to system.

Answer (score 0):

The `virtualenv` python package was not installed so I installed virtualenv package:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

and

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```